# Moq with relative DateTime values

Tags: datetime, moq

I'm a bit puzzled why this doesn't work. Probably overlooking something simple.

In the code I'm calling

```
_view.ResponseExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

In the unit test:

```
_mockView.SetupSet(v => v.ResponseExpiresAbsolute, It.Is<DateTime>(p => p < DateTime.Today));
```

The setup never matches (verifies). I've even tried something like:

```
_mockView.SetupSet(v => v.ResponseExpiresAbsolute, It.IsAny<DateTime>()));
```

with no luck.

I've stepped through the code in test and it definitely executes _view.ResponseExpiresAbsolute.

Obviously there's something up with DateTime that I'm not understanding. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try a different overload of SetupSet or even just VerifySet.

```
_mockView.VerifySet(v=>v.ResponseExpiresAbsolute = It.IsAny<DateTime>());
```